# OS X Get all registered font locations

Tags: c++, macos, qt, fonts

I'm having trouble finding all the font locations registered with OS X.
We've got the obvious locations:

```
~/Library/Fonts/
/Library/Fonts/
/System/Library/Fonts/
etc., etc.
```

However, apps can register extra locations, such as Adobe TypeKit, which registers this location:

```
/Library/Application Support/Adobe/CoreSync/plugins/livetype/.r
```

Does anyone know of a way to query all such 'additional' locations (which the system is clearly aware of).
NSFontManager doesn't seem to have this ability.

We're using Qt5 for our interface, so the obvious answer is:

```
QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::FontsLocation);
```

However this only returns 2 locations and as Qt 5 also no longer provides an API to get the freetype handle we're left dancing around getting paths. Both these Qt *problems* are logged issues.

Once we have the locations, everything else is cross platform - they go into FreeType and the decomposed outlines can get vectorised.

Any ideas appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: You can vectorise any font outline using `QPainterPath`. Do you still need to deal with font locations and freetype explicitly?

Comment: I had the same issue and ended up only using those first three folders that you mention (hardcoded, I didn't end up using `QStandardPaths::FontsLocation` as it doesn't return them all anyway). I would be very interested to know if you find a solution. Also did you solve this on the Windows side? I couldn't find a way of mapping font names in the registry to an actual path on disk other than using DirectWrite so I still have some missing fonts on Windows as well...

Comment: Interesting about QPainterPath - If I were to use HTML for formatting the text (as you can't set kerning and leading scales with QFonts) that might work. Would be a lot less code too :) Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Sorry Uflex, I didn't solve this on the Windows side, I was going there next. I'm still interested in a solution, so I'll let you know if one appears.